How to irun Python file in Android Studio on Windows
I tried to run my python file so I followed this instructions on the Interent. Here's the link.
https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#project-setup
I set my build.gradle file on project level
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://chaquo.com/maven" }
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.2' apply false
}

dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0"
    classpath 'com.chaquo.python:gradle:15.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

and here's my build.gradle file on app level.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id("com.chaquo.python")
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.fouryou'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fouryou"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abifilters "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

chaquopy {
    defaultConfig {
        buildPython("C:/Users/sally/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe")
        buildPython("python.exe")
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.7'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.7'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'

}

and my settings.gradle file is like
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}


plugins {
    id("com.chaquo.python") version "15.0.1" apply false
}

rootProject.name = "FourYou"
include ':app'


I couldn't understand what's the problem with my code.
The Error code is
Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please help me to run the Python files on the Android Studio on Windows.
Thank you very much.
I really want to run the python files on my android app

Your top-level build file is using a broken mixture of the old and new plugins syntax. Here's the simplest way to fix it:

Delete the buildscript and dependencies blocks from the project-level build.gradle.
Move the plugins block from settings.gradle to the project-level build.gradle.

